# IUseFixture.SetFixture() method is not called

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

```
public class MyTest : IUseFixture<MyFixture>
{
    [Scenario]
    public void IntegrationTest()
    {
    }

    public void SetFixture(MyFixture data)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

The `SetFixture()` method is never called. Any ideas how to fix this?

UPD The Dispose() method of the fixture object is called, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement the `IDisposable` interface explicitely as well.

```
public class MyTest : IUseFixture<MyFixture>, IDisposable
```

Comment: Not really. It's not called even if created. Dispose() of the fixture object is called, though.